# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML simple weight conversion

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I'm trying to convert lbs to kgs. Say ${item.lbs} / 2.205. I tried assign kgs = 2.205, then ${item.lbs / kgs}.. but it won't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what exactly is the problem ? Are you getting an error, or do the numbers look incorrect ? Could you include the longer example of what is in the markup to put the code in context.

Comment: Free marker error: Left hand operand expected a number but this has evaluated to sequence + has+ string

Comment: The error message in your comment says that `item.lbs` is not a number, but some more complex object.

Comment: is it for a custom record? there is no item.lbs field in vanilla Netsuite.

Comment: Yes, custom. Custom dynamic field for the lbs. And static field for kgs with value 2.205.

Comment: @porsche What type is the lbs field ?